# Importing PNG series with Import Image as Plane is blurred and has artefacts

Tags: rendering, image, add-on, antialiasing, transparency

I am using a series of .png images (from green screen footage) with alpha channels. However, when I try to import image(s) as plane(s) in a rendered scene, the image is blurry with anti-aliasing off. If I turn on anti-aliasing, then I get a frame artifact around the image plane.

Also, is there a way to setup the plane so objects behind transparent parts of the image can be seen? I am using Blender Internal and an AMD Radeon HD 5770 graphics card.

Comment: Welcome! I modified your original title to narrow the scope a little, some details were conveyed in the tags already.

Answer (score 10):

Nice default settings are to make sure you have *Z Transparency* as shown below in the *Alpha Mode* group.. also tick *Shadeless* as this makes them insensitive to light or shadow and will make them *not* appear blurry when rendered. You can enable this before or after importing the image(s).

[image]

The images come in clean with the alpha setup nicely. As you can see, they can also be layered etc, they might look a bit aliased in the 3d viewport but when rendered show very nicely.

I think the *artefacts* you might have seen is because they are intersecting with each other, try spacing them apart a bit on the *Z axis* etc..

These are the planes below in the 3d viewport after importing, the ones on the left have been spaced, while the ones on the right are in the default position.

[image]
[image]

This is how they look **without** *Shadeless* enabled when rendered.

[image]

And this is how they look **with** *Shadeless* enabled when rendered.

[image]

Comment: PNG images in general should not be set to Premultiplied alpha mode, as they are Straight alpha according to the PNG specification. If that part didn't solve any problem I suggest to remove it from the answer.

Comment: @brecht as I did not know exactly how his setup was, I merely added it just in case. Duly noted, I think the shadeless bit was what he had problems with.