# White edge around objects with alpha

Tags: game-engine, materials, transparency, opengl

I have a simple texture, of a bush (for a billboard plane)
There are very annoying white artifacts around the edge of the plane.

I am using GLSL shading in the BGE.

[image: Picture of the problem would normally be here. Problem is in the 3D view Contrasted to no problem in the image editor]

**UV/Image Editor**                             **3D View**

There is no white edge on the actual texture, however, one appears on the plane.

**Texture Settings are Below, Material Settings are below and to the right**

[image: Picture of the texture settings would normally be here][image: Picture of the material settings would normally be here]

[Blend file](https://github.com/VScalia/RadishZombies/blob/master/props/Plants.blend?raw=true)

[Textures](https://github.com/VScalia/RadishZombies/tree/master/textures)

Get the ones that start with Bush1_ and Plants_

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1625/599

Comment: Hence why I said "related" ;) Does the artifact appear in the game? Or only in the viewport?

Comment: Have you played with the pre-mult alpha option in the texture panel? THis usually alleviates the problem. It would also help if you can share the texture so we can be sure texture is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the material **Game Settings** section change **Alpha Blend** from **Opaque** to **Alpha Clip**, and in Transparency section you can adjust the Clipping amount by increasing or decreasing the Alpha value.

[image]

Comment: This totally fixed my problem. (the leaves look a bit smaller now, but it is so much better!) I'd kinda like to know what is causing this in the first place so I can prevent it for the future.

Comment: @X-27 I assume that the artifacts on the edges caused by the image compression.

Comment: the image is a .png There shouldn't be any weird compression.

Comment: @X-27 I just saw that the alpha channel has a white color, usually what happens is that people use another image as an alpha mask that has the shape of the background, and if the color is not the same as the color of unmasked pixels, the blend between the alpha and the rest of the image will create the visible artifacts where the border is.

Comment: That kinda makes sense, but I hand drew this texture in Photoshop, and I wasn't using a mask, could it just be the way that Photoshop handles the alpha channel?

Comment: @X-27 I'm not sure about that, but I've seen a lot of textures that have a different color alpha channel that resulting in that king of artifacts. I am mainly doing alpha textures with blender, because I experienced same issue with other software.

Comment: At least I know what is probably causing this, thanks!