# UV mapping artifact - Black edge (alpha area)

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

What could the problem be? Thanks!

[image: Alpha Bug]

Comment: Does it render like this? Viewport Alpha is generally lower quality.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1625/599

Comment: Can you post images of your UVs and how your material is created? Posting a blend file would be the fastest way to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Planes with transparency on them will always look this way in the viewport.This is because, as a way to be able to render the view port quicker, blender simplifies the transparency: instead of rendering the gradient from solid color to transparent, it renders a gradient going from solid color to grey, and only the fully transparent parts of the image will show the face behind them. This is expected behavior for the viewport.

When you render the scene, it will render the transparency as expected.