# Problems with Import images as planes. Display behaves randomly(artifacts)

Tags: texturing, game-engine, add-on, image, import

I am trying to import jpg-images in Blender (Blender 2.69). I am using Multitexture and a Nvidia Quadro FX 1500. I am using the Add-on "Import Images as Planes". But I have a problem. The images aren't always displayed properly. Shown in the screenshots below. (They are so blurry because I exported them in low quality.) When importing the images I don't have also the options mentioned in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/importing-png-series-with-import-image-as-plane-is-blurred-and-has-artefacts).

To show my problem I imported the same images twice in Blender: [image: imported].

I didn't scale or transformed them (yet). I want to transform them later on. If they get blurry or so I don't care.

But when I start the gaming engine I get following results, (they are completely random, sometimes both are right or wrong or 1 is correct and the other is strange). I tried png-images but with the same result. I also didn't change the viewport between those screenshots:
[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]

Does anyone have an idea, what causes this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Addition:
I was able to test it on another PC. On that it was displayed correctly. So I guess it is a hardware problem. Are there any settings I could change to make it work?

Comment: Please give graphics card model and render method for blendergame (multitexture, GLSL... ) –

Comment: I added it into the post.

Comment: I'm not so sure why this can occur, but it seems that something wrong with the UV. like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/66060) and [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/66061).

Comment: I added a new remark.

Comment: I think could be a problem with your graphic card. **Make sure you had the latest drivers** and put the default configuration. This happened to me also when I put the 3d configuration of my old NVIDIA 440MX to really low quality graphics. **Try to look if your Quadro had the configuration on defaults on your NVIDIA PANEL**.

Comment: While this is more of a bug than a question, I don't feel that there is any intrinsic value in putting it on hold. If somebody does have a working solution, it is only beneficial to post it as an answer. Perhaps I am simply conflicted about SE's system, but I also feel it's not hugely important to put it on hold as the question itself doesn't have any further problems.